# Ruby loop index variable publishing continuously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I am working on a rails based app that processes large files which takes time. The main part of the function is a `.each_with_index` loop.

My controller for the endpoint looks like this:

def

```
 import
  FileImporter.import()
  render json: 1
end
```

I would like to expose the index variable from the loop and continuously update the screen with it so I can build a percentage update bar to show the progress.

In Java there is a `publish` method for worker threads to intermittently publish such things for that kind of purpose. Is there an equivalent in Ruby?

Also presumably I would need to run the `import()` method on a separate thread then which the webserver would need to support. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. What are you exactly trying to do? you can not pass index from `each_with_index` on view to controller to update progress bar on runtime, if that's what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a long running job it probably makes sense to use an actual job system for that work. (eg. Sidekiq, Resque, etc.) That job could publish its progress to a known location, such as a database field.

You could then have a Rails endpoint that queries the value of that field and returns it. Add a little JavaScript on the front-end and you have periodic updates in the UI.